# The main loop of my SFML project happens only once. Anybody know why?

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm making a game in SFML and I have been making it my PC at home. Lately I had to take my project with me and continue coding it on a different PC. I configured Code::Blocks for SFML on the new PC and I opened the project and i wanted to compile it to see if it worked fine. As soon as the program window opened and all the textures have been drawn, the program crashed. I went through the code and i noticed that the main loop of the program ( which is: while(win.isOpen()) ) happened only once. I tried to fix it by rewriting parts of the code but nothing worked. Since I am a very novice programmer i have no idea how to fix this of what  is causing this error. Also if you see some ways i could improve my code i would be greatfull if you could point ot those ways:D Thanks.

So here is the main loop if the game. There are sevral other files included to the project, so i figured to not post all of the files.

```
while(win.isOpen())
{
    win.clear();
    win.draw(bg);
    Sprite rom[24];
    rom[0].setTexture(ro[12]);
    r[0].id=1;
    if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D))
    {
        if(x<1200)
            x=x+10;
    }
    if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A))
    {
        if(x>1)
            x=x-10;
    }
    if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::S))
    {
        if(y<900)
            y=y+10;
    }
    if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::W))
    {
        if(y>1)
            y=y-10;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<=23; i++)
    {
        if(r[i].if_draw==true)
        {
            if(r[i].type==1 && r[i].siz==1)
            {
                rom[i].setTexture(ro[0]);
            }
            if(r[i].type==1 && r[i].siz==2)
            {
                rom[i].setTexture(ro[1]);
            }
            if(r[i].type==1 && r[i].siz==3)
            {
                rom[i].setTexture(ro[2]);
            }
            if(r[i].type==2 && r[i].siz==1)
            {
                rom[i].setTexture(ro[3]);
            }
            if(r[i].type==2 && r[i].siz==2)
            {
                rom[i].setTexture(ro[4]);
            }
            if(r[i].type==2 && r[i].siz==3)
            {
                rom[i].setTexture(ro[5]);
            }
            if(r[i].type==3 && r[i].siz==1)
            {
                rom[i].setTexture(ro[6]);
            }
            if(r[i].type==3 && r[i].siz==2)
            {
                rom[i].setTexture(ro[7]);
            }
            if(r[i].type==3 && r[i].siz==3)
            {
                rom[i].setTexture(ro[8]);
            }
            if(r[i].type==4 && r[i].siz==1)
            {
                rom[i].setTexture(ro[9]);
            }
            if(r[i].type==4 && r[i].siz==2)
            {
                rom[i].setTexture(ro[10]);
            }
            if(r[i].type==4 && r[i].siz==3)
            {
                rom[i].setTexture(ro[11]);
            }
            get_cords(sx,sy,r[i].id);
            rom[i].setPosition(sx,sy);
            win.draw(rom[i]);
        }
    }
    while(win.pollEvent(e))
    {
        if(e.type==e.KeyPressed && e.key.code==Keyboard::Space)
        {
            if((y<=750 && y>=150) && (x>=150 && x<=1050))
            {
                sel_space=get_sel_space(x,y);
                sel_row=get_row(sel_space);
                win.draw(options_b_1);
                win.display();
                sel_type=get_sel_number(e,win);
                if(sel_type==7)
                {
                    sel_type=0;
                    sel_space=0;
                    sel_size=0;
                    sel_row=0;

                    break;
                }
                if(sel_type==6 && sel_space!=1)
                {
                    row_t[sel_row-1]=row_t[sel_row-1]-r[sel_space-1].siz;
                    r[sel_space-1].demolish();
                }
                else if(sel_type!=7 && sel_space!=1)
                {
                    win.draw(options_b_2);
                    win.display();
                    r[sel_space-1].if_draw=true;
                    for(;;)
                    {
                        sel_size=get_sel_number(e,win);
                        if((sel_size>=1 && sel_size<=3) || (sel_size==7))
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(chk_id_size(sel_space,sel_size)==true)
                    {
                        if(sel_size>=1 && sel_size<=3)
                        {
                            if_b=chk_if_good_space(r,row_t[sel_row-1],sel_size,sel_space-1,sel_row);
                        }
                        else if(sel_size==7)
                        {
                            sel_type=0;
                            sel_space=0;
                            sel_size=0;
                            sel_row=0;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if_b=false;
                    }
                    if(if_b==true)
                    {
                        chk_money_pay(money,sel_type,sel_size);
                        r[sel_space-1].id=sel_space;
                        r[sel_space-1].type=sel_type;
                        r[sel_space-1].siz=sel_size;
                        r[sel_space-1].occ=true;
                        if(sel_size==2)
                        {
                            r[sel_space].occ=true;
                        }
                        if(sel_size==3)
                        {
                            r[sel_space].occ=true;
                            r[sel_space+1].occ=true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<=23; i++)
    {
        rom[i].~Sprite();
    }
    pointer.setPosition(x,y);
    win.draw(pointer);
    win.display();
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you manually calling the destructor with `rom[i].~Sprint()`?  This is done automatically when the variable goes out of scope.

Comment: Because the textures in my game inside the  rom[ ] Sprites have to be versitile. At one point the sprite has to contain a certain texture, then it has to have a different texture, and somtimes it has to have no texture at all to not draw anything. Because of that last part, i couldn't find any other way to delete the texture inside the sprite, so at the end of every iteration of the main loop i use the destructor and on the start of the main loop i set the refreshed textures back into the sprites.

Answer (score 1):

You're manually calling the destructors for your `Sprite` array (`rom[i].~Sprite`).  This results in Undefined Behavior when the loop iteration ends and the compiler calls the destructors when the lifetime of `rom` ends at the end of the loop.  Undefined behavior means it can do anything, including working on one system and crashing on another.

Running your code in a debugger, and seeing where it crashes, can clue you in:  you want to get rid of the loop that calls `~Sprite`.

Comment: I removed that loop that calls the destructors for the rom Sprites and it works fine now. Thanks for the help :)